# Python: Issue with datetime.timestamp | Date March 26, 2017, 01:55, 02:55, 03:55

Tags: python-3.x, sublimetext2, python-idle

I am stumped by a peculiar situation where I am creating epoch time stamps of my input files to check for duplicates. After I run the code, I get duplicate errors, although in reality there are no duplicates.

INPUT 1 (CSV file with fence separator):

```
1:55|The Chris Ramsey Show|||3/26/2017
2:25|South Park|The Biggest Douche in the Universe|615|3/26/2017
2:55|South Park|My Future Self 'n' Me|616|3/26/2017
```

Duplicates found in INPUT 1 (result from my code):

```
(i.e., programs with the same start time and date):
(1490489700, '01:55', 'The Chris Ramsey Show', '', '03/26/2017')
(1490489700, '02:55', 'South Park', "My Future Self 'n' Me", '03/26/2017')
```

INPUT 2 (CSV file with fence separator):

```
3/26/2017|2:55|The Chris Ramsey Show|30|||103|Episode 3
3/26/2017|3:25|South Park|30|||615|The Biggest Douche in the Universe
3/26/2017|3:55|South Park|20|||616|My Future Self n' Me
```

Duplicates found in INPUT 2 (result from my code):

```
(i.e., programs with the same start time and date):
(1490493300, '02:55', 'The Chris Ramsey Show', 'Episode 3', '03/26/2017')
(1490493300, '03:55', 'South Park', "My Future Self n' Me", '03/26/2017')
```

Upon debugging, I found 3 different time periods that were causing this issue.

```
03/26/2017 01:55
03/26/2017 02:55
03/26/2017 03:55
```

I tried replicating this issue directly in Python, and hence created the below code:

```
import datetime
t1 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 1, 55)
t2 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 2, 55)
t3 = datetime.datetime(2017, 3, 26, 3, 55)
print(t1, t1.timestamp())
print(t2, t2.timestamp())
print(t3, t3.timestamp())
```

Even more confusing, Sublime Text 2 Python IDE and IDLE are giving 2 different duplicates.

Output from Sublime Text 2 IDE:

```
2017-03-26 01:55:00 1490489700.0
2017-03-26 02:55:00 1490489700.0
2017-03-26 03:55:00 1490493300.0
[Finished in 0.1s]
```

Output from IDLE:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 07:18:10) [MSC v.1900 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> 
================== RESTART: C:\Users\<>\Desktop\test.py ==================
2017-03-26 01:55:00 1490489700.0
2017-03-26 02:55:00 1490493300.0
2017-03-26 03:55:00 1490493300.0
>>>
```

Of course, I could try using a different code to get the epoch time, but I wanted to know why this issue occurs.

Answer (score 0):

When I run your code as is, I get 3 different timestamps in both 3.5.3 and 3.6.1.

```
2017-03-26 01:55:00 1490507700.0
2017-03-26 02:55:00 1490511300.0
2017-03-26 03:55:00 1490514900.0
```

When I change the date to 3-12, the 'spring forward' date for changing time in the USA, I get different duplicates with 3.5 and 3.6 respectively.

```
# 3.5
2017-03-12 01:55:00 1489301700.0
2017-03-12 02:55:00 1489301700.0
2017-03-12 03:55:00 1489305300.0

# 3.6
2017-03-12 01:55:00 1489301700.0
2017-03-12 02:55:00 1489305300.0
2017-03-12 03:55:00 1489305300.0
```

My conclusion is that a) next Sunday is the 'spring forward' date in your country, and b) Sublime Text runs 3.5.  The method for disambiguating ambiguous (repeated) times was changed in 3.6. See the doc to datetime.timestamp.

Comment: This information is news to me. I appreciate your sharing this feedback.